# Wordpress theme script do not change after modification / register

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've modified a script of an theme. After loading without any caching in any browser it does not seems to change at all. I can even delete the script file, but the unchanged script gets loaded from the browser anyway. I've downloaded the entire folder and searched for this functionality. It can be only this file.
How is it possible or how can i solve my problem. I've seen function that register this script for some reason. Maybe i need to unregister and reregister it ?

```
wp_register_script('ci-front-scripts', get_child_or_parent_file_uri('/js/scripts.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to enqueue this script:

```
function my_script_register() {
    wp_register_script('ci-front-scripts', get_child_or_parent_file_uri('/js/scripts.js', array(), true);
    wp_enqueue_script('ci-front-scripts');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_register');
```

for the function `wp_register_script` you also need dependencies array (I've made it empty in code sample) and either to require it in `wp_footer()` or `wp_head()`. Set to true (as in code sample) will require the script in `wp_footer()` action.

Comment: Just modified a working theme. There is an wp_enqueue_script. I'm not sure if i need to call it after changes like i said or it gets called every time.

Comment: @MR.ABC can you share the code of a function you've changed?

Comment: Its just javascript. It has nothing to do with the content really.

Comment: @MR.ABC you may try use `wp_deregister_script('ci-front-scripts');` and check if it works as expected (script should not appear on the page). Also you can check your website in other browser to see it's not a browser cache problem. Also you can try clearing browser cache for the same reason.